# MS SQL Server Management Studio. cannot remotely connected to a server, why and how?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to take off firewalls, It is still not connected;

> Cannot connect to ACER2\SQLEXPRESS;
>   Additional information: A network=related or instance-specific error occurred while established a "....." Error:26, (Error Locating Server SErver/ locating server/instance specific)

I took off the firewall and am able to see my current data   Result is that the the other computer is able to see/load my current databases. but I cannot vice versa.

Comment: is it sqlserver 2012?

Comment: SQL Server **Express** does *not* allow remote connections by default - [you need to explicitly allow remote connections!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx)

Comment: IT is SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the following ?

1. Turned off Anti-Virus
2. Enable remote connections to this server
3. Enable TCP/IP protocol in SQL Server Manager
4. Checked if SQL Server and SQL Server Browser are running

Comment: I will take a look one by one.... thx. However, the server apparently can connect back to my computer (as server) using SQL management. Like, from the server, I open the SQL management studio\browse for more... It shows my computer is on it. However, on my computer SQL management studio\Browse for servers, it shows only the local server "SQLEXPRESS"